# set my objects to left of the columns in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 in my website.
I created a row that looks like the following image, within this row, i've created 4 columns:
Left: picture
L-R: text
L-L: Input
Right: Button

[image]

**Where is my problem** ?
1. Set the user/password/input/login button to the left of the columns
2. set button height small
3. "Forgot your password" to be in 1 line and not 2 lines.

Like the following picture:

[image]

I am new to HTML/CSS. How can i achieve it ?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row loginBody">
  <div class="col-md-4 "></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
  <div class="container-fluid InputLoginDetails LoginFont">
    <div class="row LoginRow">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="img/Hello.png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      User:
      Password:
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">

     <p>Forgot your password?</p>

     </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">Login</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.loginBody{
background-color: #808689;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 5%;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.LoginRow{
padding-top: 3%;
padding-bottom: 3%;
background-color: white;
}
.LoginFont{
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #7296cd;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
padding-top: 5%;
}
.InputLoginDetails input[type="text"] {
 height: 1.1em;
 font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at this. http://www.bootply.com/T191UHM0jK If this is what you want, I'll create an answer and explain what i changed.

Comment: @Sebsemillia - that was very nice of you. I really wish people would read the docs and use the correct form classes and structure as you have done.

Comment: @ilansch Here an updated version that looks more like your 2nd screenshot: http://www.bootply.com/wHnS3Vnl1M

Comment: Thats what i want, the only thing that i see in your sample also, is that there is plenty of space between the pic and User/Password label, I want to align it to the left, to save room..

Comment: @Christina Thank you! :) Yes I would explain his markup / structure mistakes if he asks me to create an answer. ;)

Comment: I'd be happy for an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed several things in your `HTML` markup.

1.) You don't use `.container` classes within a row, they are just used as containers **outside** of rows.

> Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

[Bootstrap Containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

2.) You don't need 4 columns within your '.LoginRow', one for the image and one for the form elements are sufficient and give you more flexibility.

3.) Use the [horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) markup of bootstrap to create the form layout.

4.) All in all, you need to take a closer look at the Bootstrap docs and their examples, especially the grid system. Then it is really easy to do a lot of things.

Here is your changed HTML markup:

```
<div class="row loginBody">
  <div class="col-md-4 "></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
  <div class="InputLoginDetails LoginFont">

    <div class="row LoginRow">
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                         <p>Forgot your password?</p>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </form>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You said you wanted to align the User/Password label to the left. Since the bootstrap default labes are aligned to the right, I created this `CSS` additionally:

```
.LoginRow .form-group label {
    text-align: left;
  }
```

And here is a working [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6gDAg9KHXW)

Comment: Can I Align the User/Password labels to be more left than they are ? in your sample the text box is over the label

Comment: This depends on your screen resolution, you just have to change the `col-xx-x` until it fits your needs for each resolution. Again, take a look at the bootstrap grid system. Here is a changed version, maybe this looks better on your resolution: http://www.bootply.com/l8GjBf6MUE

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, and with the code you have provided. I think you didnt have to add both labels with the same div and input boxes. Please check the fiddle to see if thats what you wanted.

I also removed the `<p> tag from "Forgot your password".`

**I changed**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
      User:
      Password:
    </div>
```

**To**

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
  User:
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ycswckh1/)